# How to change formats of multiple variables in one dataset?

Tags: r

I have 6 variables in my data, one is the date, other five are numerical. When I imported the file, date was in `character`, 2 numerical variables remained `numeric`, and the 3 other variables seemed to be changed to `character`. I want to know the reason behind it and now if I want to change all of their formats, how can I do that?

Comment: Please do some search on this site. You will find all answers here, providing some limited effort.

Comment: This is completely dependent on how you're importing your data. It would be good if you could provide more details. but generally, this will be answered somewhere on SO like others have said.

Comment: ##Well I tried & did it myself.But the column which contains the date of transaction, I'm still working on it but it keeps me giving NA value in all the rows of the column only,rest of the columns are now good.
My code for the date column is:
>kids_store2$month<-as.Date(kids_store2$month,format="%D-%m-%Y")

I have tried a lot of ways depicted here as answers for other similar problems but still no improvement.If anyone could help me do share, n of course I will keep trying until it's solved.

Comment: @ArijitChaki Hi, if any answer solves your problem can you click on "accept it" so that other people can see it? thanks

Answer (score 1):

When importing a .csv file (I assume it is what you did), you must be careful with some stuff:

- Columns containing numbers are transformed into characters if there is one or more cells marked as `#ERROR` or `#DIV/0` or any other `NA` strings that have not been clearly mentioned as such. Sometimes, with analytical data, you get detection limit results such as `<0.02` and it is interpreted as text.
- Date in character is rather predictable and often happens when importing.

Anyway, if you need to force some columns to specific classes when importing a .csv file, there is the very useful `colClasses` argument. When using `NA`, R automatically picks the best format. Try something like this:

```
df <- read.csv(file="input.csv", na.strings=c("", "#REF", "#DIV/0"), colClasses=c(Date, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA))
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment...

```
kids_store2$month = format(as.Date(d, format = "%d-%m-%Y"),"%m")
```

This will return the month as an integer.

(Assuming dates are in dd-mm-yyyy ("28-04-2015") format.)